# location.search not redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in my js:

```
var data = "newValue";
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
      var params = location.href.split('?')[1].replace(/#.*/g,'');
      location.hash = 'myhash';
      location.search = params + '&newData='+ data;

    });
```

it always change the url I can see in the browser, but it's not always launched.

what is my problem?

Comment: what does mean  "not always launched"?

Answer (score 2):

To change the value of search parameter in angular, you just need to do:

```
$location.search('someVar','newValue');
```

Comment: if you want to redirect after change use
`location.reload()`

Comment: thanks, my solution was very close, its location.replace();